# Calculating a limit

Tags: matrices, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Let $A$ be a $k \times k$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $det(A) = \pm 1$. Consider the hyperbolic toral automorphism $f_A : T^k \to T^k$, $f_A(x) = Ax \;\text{mod}\; 1$. We know that the set of all periodic points of period $n$ has the cardinal $P_n(f_A)$ equal to $|det(A^n - I)| = |(\lambda_1^n - 1)...(\lambda_k^n - 1)|$, where $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

I can't show that the following limit exists
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{P_n(f_A)}{\lambda^n},$$
for some $\lambda > 0$.
Can someone give me a hint? Thank you!

P.S: I think that $\lambda = \underset{|\lambda_i| > 1}{\sum} \lambda_i$.

Comment: It might help to note that, in fact, $$|\det(A^n - I)| = |(\lambda_1^n - 1)\cdots(\lambda_k^n - 1)|$$

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you replace $$\lambda = \underset{|\lambda_i| > 1}{\sum} \lambda_i\quad\text{by}\quad \lambda = \underset{|\lambda_i| > 1}{\prod} \lambda_i,$$ then the limit in question is $1$. This is the usual format, and the beginning of many other discussions on the asymptotics of more general hyperbolic dynamics.

Somewhat "easy" consequence: the topological entropy is $\log\lambda$.

Comment: Each term $\lambda_i^n-1$ with $|\lambda_i|<1$ tends to $1$. For the others, it is $(\lambda_i^n-1)/\lambda_i^n$ that tends to $1$.